# SQL Counting with Text Comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, count

Is it possible to do a count in sql based off of a text function?  I want to count the instances of a zip code (which is of type `DECIMAL`), however, some rows have the 5 digit zip, while the others have the 9 digit zip.

My current query:

```
select patzip, count(patzip) as zip_count 
from patdemo_t 
where patstate='KY' 
group by patzip 
order by zip_count desc
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),patzip), 1, 5) zip, COUNT(*) zip_count
  FROM patdemo_t
 WHERE patstate = 'KY'
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), patzip), 1, 5)
 ORDER BY zip DESC
```

Sample output:

```
|   ZIP | ZIP_COUNT |
---------------------
| 41017 |         2 |
| 41016 |         1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4990f/2)** demo

Comment: That gives me the total. I need it for each 5 digit zip code.  I need to build a census by zip code for a given state.  Right now, I have:
select patzip, count(patzip) as zip_count
from patdemo_t
where patstate='KY'
group by patzip
order by zip_count desc

This gives me all zip codes, and the counts, however, it treats each code differently.  I need the first 5 digits to be used as the base for counting.  So 41017 and 410179876 would increase the count for 41017.

Comment: So I think that will work, except the patzip field is of type decimal, which evidently you can't use in a substring function.

Comment: @StevenThompson See updated answer. You have to include this details in your question in the first place (RDMBMS that you're using, table schema, sample data, desired output, your current query wether it's working or not). It saves time and effort for you and for those who help you.

Comment: You the man!  I will be better about it next time.  Sorry, first time post.